# how i can exchange y1 axis with y2 axis in nvd3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

i'm newbie in javascript especially using nvd3.js, but i want to visualize data-data using nvd3.js. I have tried nvd3.js and part of my code is :

```
var chart;

nv.addGraph(function() {
chart = nv.models.linePlusBarChart()
    .margin({top: 30, right: 60, bottom: 50, left: 70})
    .x(function(d,i) { return i })
    .color(d3.scale.category10().range());

chart.xAxis
  .tickFormat(function(d) {
      var dx = testdata[0].values[d] && testdata[0].values[d].x || 0;
      return dx ? d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(dx)) : '';
      })
  .showMaxMin(false)
  .axisLabel("X-axis Label");

chart.y1Axis
    .tickFormat(d3.format(',f'))
    .axisLabel("y1Axis Label");

chart.y2Axis
    .tickFormat(function(d) { return '$' + d3.format(',.2f')(d) })
    .axisLabel("y2Axis Label");


chart.bars.forceY([0]).padData(false);
//chart.lines.forceY([0]);


d3.select('#chart1 svg')
    .datum(testdata)
    .transition().duration(500).call(chart);

nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

chart.dispatch.on('stateChange', function(e) { nv.log('New State:', JSON.stringify(e)); });

return chart;
```

full code in here : http://jsfiddle.net/8ZVLJ/2/

i want to exchange y1 axis in left side to be right side and y2 axis in right side to be left side, i have tried, but still not work, how i can do that?

Thanks